# Detect and access external RS-232 signal within Android

Tags: android, serial-port

During a normal Peloton ride, the bike's resistance setting is transmitted to the Android display via a RS-232 signal from the bike hardware.  I would like to access this resistance value from within Android.  I hope to write a small app that would display the resistance level on the Android notification bar.  This would allow me to view this value while running sideloaded apps on the Peloton display.  There are several devices available that intercept the RS-232 signal, but I would like to access these values from within the Android display.

I have used the "Serial USB Terminal" app to look for USB serial ports.  I only see devices for the network and ANT+ adapters.  Obviously, I do not have root access.

How would I determine where this value might be exposed within Android?

Comment: I think this question would better fit to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com unless Peleton provides API documentation. If I would be in your position I would try to extract the app that shows the values you are after and decompile it to see where the values come from, e.g. if there is a private Peleton API.